# How to propery listen to child changes in FirebaseDatabase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to listen to my database child changes, in my case it is orders.

Below is a picture of my database, where
ODdPag... Is the uid of my customer

Lu-_1A is just `.push` random order naming

[image]

I can provide my code but it is confusing and not working, because i can only access Orders and not its next child.

Now I want to list all my orders and lister for changes in sub children (in order names) not uid.

I am using:

```
val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.reference
val ref = db.child("/Orders/")

ref.addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener {

            override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {

                ringtone.play()

                itemListTable.clear()
                p0.children.forEach {
                    it.child("order").children.forEach{ item ->
                        val newData = item.getValue(itemListData::class.java) ?: return
                        newData.itemName = item.key!!
                        newData.orderKey = it.key!!
                        itemListTable.add(newData)

                    }
                    val data = it.getValue(itemRowData::class.java) ?: return
                    adapter.add(itemRow(data.phoneNumber,data.time,data.locationLat,data.locationLong,data.optionalAddress,data.optionalNote,data.totalPrice,itemListTable,it.key))
                }
            }


            override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {

                Log.d("ac1234","$p0")
                    p0.child("order").children.forEach{ item ->
                        Log.d("ac1234","1")
                        val newData = item.getValue(itemListData::class.java) ?: return
                        Log.d("ac1234","2")
                        newData.itemName = item.key!!
                        newData.orderKey = p0.key!!
                        itemListTable.add(newData)}


                    val data = p0.getValue(itemRowData::class.java) ?: return
                    adapter.add(itemRow(data.phoneNumber,data.time,data.locationLat,data.locationLong,data.optionalAddress,data.optionalNote,data.totalPrice,itemListTable,p0.key))

            }
```

```
class itemRowData(val phoneNumber :String = "",val time :String = "",val locationLat :Double = 0.0,val locationLong :Double = 0.0,val optionalAddress :String = "",val optionalNote :String = "",val totalPrice :String = "")
class itemListData(var itemName: String = "" ,val totalQuantity: String = "",val totalPrice :Long = 0,var orderKey :String = "")
```

Logcat: 1 and 2 are not called

P0 shows 4 rows full of all data every time I send an order

Comment: *"i can only access Orders and not its next child"* - what exactly does that mean?  What are you trying to accomplish?  I do suggest editing the question to add your code, even if it doesn't work, in order to help us understand what you're doing.

Comment: If your application code is too confusing to post, reproduce the problem in isolation. "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Please add the code that you are using even if it doesn't work. Please also respond with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i added my code and some infos

Comment: @DougStevenson i added my code above

Comment: @nickisra You want to get all orders that correspond to a specific user `ODdPag...` or all orders from all users?

Comment: @AlexMamo i want all orders from all users, that is my problem. I cant reference to every ("/Orders/uid") to listen to child changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want all orders from all users, that is my problem. I cant reference to every ("/Orders/uid") to listen to child changes

To get all orders of all users, you should use a `ValueEventListener`, like in the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val ordersRef = rootRef.child("Orders")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (uidDataSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
            for (orderDataSnapshot in uidDataSnapshot.children) {
                val newData = orderDataSnapshot.getValue(itemListData::class.java)
                itemListTable.add(newData)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
ordersRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener)
```

See, in order to get each order of each user, you should iterate twice, once to get the `uidDataSnapshot` and then to get the `orderDataSnapshot` object.

Comment: Does value event listener get upated every time a user sends an order?

Comment: I tried your solution, it worked but only to get all orders. its working the same as my old code ('onChildAdded') but the problem is that i need to listen for new orders, in my (ChildEventListener - > onDataChange)

Comment: In this case, please see my updated answer where I have changed the method from `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` call to `addValueEventListener`. Does it work now the way you want?

Comment: Did that, now its updating but its re adding all the orders. For example if i had 8 orders total and then i ordered 1 more, i get 20-25 orders in my list. The problem is that the snapshot i get when its a new order is a list of all orders under the uid, and not only the new order

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you make it work. What you say sounds like an adapter problem. So please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I dont think that the problem is the adapter, i will make a new question to try to get a new answer, as i am getting multiple snapshots which im not supposed. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: can you please check my new thread in which i explained my problem a little further .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942066/how-to-fix-childeventlistener-returning-multiple-data